# Generate and send PDF with external API data in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I try to generate a pdf files with data from an external api in wordpress. Im noob in php and very lost at this point.

I don't want to use plugin for this, maybe create my own.

so if you have tips or something to help me ?

At this point its maybe ok to create a plugin for call api but no idea for use result in a pdf ?

thanks